# Continue keydown event even when an additional button is pressed

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events, keyboard-events

Let's say we have a ball that can be moved left and right around the screen. When you click space, the ball should jump.

I got the ball to move left and right in a canvas. However, when the ball is moving left (for example) and I hit the space bar before anything, the ball stops moving left.

Check out [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/Q2cC5/2/) so far!

I am using the [KeyboardJS](http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/) library to handle my key events:

```
KeyboardJS.on("left", function () {
    cc();
    x -= xv;
    if (x < r) {
        circle(x + width, y, r);
        if (x + width <= width - r) {
            x = x + width;
        }
    }
    circle(x, y, r);
});

KeyboardJS.on("space", null, function () {
    console.log("space!");
});
```

How could I get this behavior to stop so that when the space bar is hit, the ball jumps up but at the same time still moves to the left?

Comment: After looking at the functionality, it would seem to me that KeyboardJS has severe onkeyup issues. They do not seem to function properly at all.

Comment: @Travis J the onkeyup seems to work fine for me. What issues are you seeing?

Comment: @forgivenson - *Egregious ones*. Basically that the onkeyup event handler wipes out any other currently running keydown event handlers. It also calls the keyup handler once *for every time* that the keydown handler ran which is horrid.

Comment: @Travis J : Ah, okay. I didn't look at the KeyboardJS code. I guess I missed that word "properly" in your comment, because I thought you were saying they didn't work at all. My mistake

Comment: I've made some major modifications to my original answer, and I've also included a working code solution to your problem. You might want to check if that is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: I've added an extra functionality to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20806310/1256925), which does exactly what you requested in your comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20807003/1256925). You might want to check it out, it's probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One thought added to everyone else's good ideas:**

*Separate your user input from your drawing.*

**Keyboarding:**

If you’re having problems with KeyboardJS, check out Keydrown: http://jeremyckahn.github.io/keydrown/

Don’t do any drawing when capturing keys…just capture the user’s input of which direction they want the circle to go.

Set up an “direction” variable to hold how many times the user has pressed [left] or [right]:

```
var direction=0;
```

When [left] is pressed:

```
direction--;
```

When [right] is pressed:

```
direction++;
```

Direction is a *net number*.  So if the user holds down the left key for 20 strokes and the right key for 15 strokes, direction will be -5  ( -20 + 15 ).

Set up an “altitude” variable to hold how many times the user has pressed [space]:

```
var altitude=0;
```

When [space] is pressed:

```
altitude-=10;
```

Altitude is a *net number* also.

**Drawing:**

Do all your drawing in a separate animation loop.  Rather than using javascript’s setInterval, use the new and improved way of creating an imation loop --  `requestAnimationFrame`.

```
// set the starting circle positions 

var currentX=canvas.width;
var currentY=canvas.height-r;

function animate(){

    // even as we're executing this current animation loop
    // request another loop for next time

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // change the currentX position by the accumulated direction

    currentX+=direction;
    direction=0;

    // change the currentY position by the accumulated altitude

    currentY+=altitude;
    altitude=0;

    // draw the circle at its current position

    cc();

    circle(currentX,currentY,r);

    // apply gravity to the circle
    // to make it fall if its in the air

    if(currentY<canvas.height-r){
        currentY++;
    }

}
```

Good Luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for the `requestAnimationFrame` suggestion! I didn't know that existed.

Comment: Thank you. The Keydrone solution has been the best so far!

Answer (score 2):

What the problem is, is that if you press another key after pressing the first key, it will trigger that event, and stop triggering the other keydown event. This can be seen in this simplified example:

```
addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {console.log(e.keyCode, e.keyIdentifier)});
```

If you run that script, and then press left and then up, it will first show `37  Left` a bunch of times, and then it'll show `32  U+0020` once and stop logging the left keydowns.

This is simply how the browser (and most other basic programs too) work. You can try doing the same thing in for example notepad, if you press the A key first, and then press space, it'll stop adding more As. This also means that you can't rely on key events (or key event libraries) to do this for you.

What you could do though, is make a global object that holds all keys that are pressed. For example:

```
window.KeysDown = {
    37: false, //Left
    39: false, //Right
    38: false, //Up
    40: false, //Down
    32: false, //Space
};

addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
     var keyCode = e.keyCode||e.charCode||e.which;
     if (keyCode == 32 && !window.KeysDown[keyCode])
         onSpace();//This will only run when the spacebar is first pressed down.
     if (window.KeysDown.hasOwnProperty(keyCode))
         window.KeysDown[keyCode] = true;
});
addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
     var keyCode = e.keyCode||e.charCode||e.which;
     if (window.KeysDown.hasOwnProperty(keyCode)) window.KeysDown[keyCode] = false;
});

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    for (var i in window.KeysDown) {
        if (window.KeysDown[i]) switch (i+'') {
            case '37': onLeft(); break;
            //case '38': window.KeysDown[i] && onUp(); break;
            case '39': onRight(); break;
            //case '40': window.KeysDown[i] && onDown(); break;
        }
    }
}, 50);
```

The syntax `window.KeysDown[i] && onLeft()` causes the `onLeft` function only to run if `window.KeysDown[i]` is true. I hope this solution works for you.

**EDIT**: I've changed the code to the working one. I've also made [a JSFiddle that demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2cC5/9/). The problem in my previous code was that apparently a switch doesn't handle integer values well, so I needed to convert `i` to a string.

**EDIT**: I've also added an extra part to the script that makes the `onSpace` function only run when the spacebar is first pressed down, and so that it won't run again until the spacebar is released and pressed again. I've also [updated my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2cC5/10/) to include these changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a main function, which runs at a regular interval, and each time it runs, it updates the position of the circle based on what keys are currently down.

The main function can be done like this:

```
var keyDown = {};

function mainLoop() {
    cc();

    //pseudo code
    if (keyDown["left"]) {
        x -= 5;
    }
    if(keyDown["space"]) {
        y -= 10;
    }

    // redraw circle at new location
    circle(x,y,r);
}

setInterval(mainLoop, 30) //sets the function to be called every 30 milliseconds

// key event handler, first function handles the keydown, second function handles keyup
KeyboardJS.on("left", function() {
    keyDown["left"] = true;
}, function() {
    keyDown["left"] = false;
});
```

With this example, if the user had the left arrow key and space bar pressed when the `mainLoop` function ran, then the circle would move to the left 5 pixels, and up 10 pixels.

Comment: This would work, although it would definitely require some finagling.

Comment: How would I determine the key down without an key event?

Comment: You could have a map of the keys and whether they are pressed or not. The keydown/keyup events would set the status of the key in the map, and then the mainLoop function would just look at the values set in the map. There may be better ways to do it though.

Comment: updated my answer the demonstrate what the keydown/keyup event handling would look like.

Comment: @forgivenson Thats what I thought I should do. Well thank you. Once I try this out I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/9naTJ/)***

You are going to have to manually create a framework for this. KeyboardJS just wasn't cutting it. I guess I kind of set that up here. It uses an Action "class" coupled with key event triggers.

*Action "class"*

```
function Actions(){
 this.count = 0;
 this.running = {};
 this.interval = undefined;
}

Actions.prototype.start = function(action){
  if( typeof(this.running[action]) == "undefined"){
     this[action]();
     this.running[action] = action;
     this.count++;
  }
  var me = this;
  if( typeof(this.interval) == "undefined"){
     this.interval = setInterval(function(){
      for( var act in me.running ){
       me[act]();
      }
     },50);
  }
};

Actions.prototype.stop = function(action){
  this.running[action] = void 0;
  delete this.running[action];
  this.count--;
  if( this.count == 0 ){
   clearInterval(this.interval);
   this.interval = void 0;
  };
};

Actions.prototype.left = function(){
 cc();
 x -= xv;
 if (x < r) {
    circle(x + width, y, r);
    if (x + width <= width - r) {
        x = x + width;
    }
 }
 circle(x, y, r);
};
Actions.prototype.right = function(){
 cc();
 x += xv;
 if (x >= width - r) {
    circle((x - r) - (width - r), y, r);
    if ((x - r) - (width - r) > r) {
        x = (x - r) - (width - r);
    }
 }
 circle(x, y, r);
};
Actions.prototype.space = function(){
 cc();
 y -= yv;
 circle(x, y, r);
};
```

*key event triggers*

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeyDown;
function checkKeyDown(e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    // left arrow
    actions.start("left");
 }
 if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    // right arrow
    actions.start("right");
 }
 if (e.keyCode == '32') {
    // space bar
    actions.start("space");
 }
}
document.onkeyup = checkKeyUp;
function checkKeyUp(e) {
 e = e || window.event;

 if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    // left arrow
    actions.stop("left");
 }
 if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    // right arrow
    actions.stop("right");
 }
 if (e.keyCode == '32') {
    // space bar
    actions.stop("space");
 }
}
```

Comment: God, I didn't think something so simple would end up being so complicated. However, what if I want the space to only register once? Once so that instead of the y just keep on going up but instead so I can add another interval when space is click to make a jump effect

Comment: @Shawn31313 - You would use a flag to lock out the addition of the space event if already present, and then have the space event call stop on its own internally once completed instead of on keyup.